# Run EXCEL VBA code in separate workbooks in sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have seven Excel workbooks that have macros to update them, and these are to be run every week.

I want to create a macro that runs each one sequentially (and closes the previous one as some subs have common names).

I created a new workbook with a macro to run them, but it only runs the first one, then stops.

I do not want to modify the VBA code in the seven workbooks as I want to be able to run them individually if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, but I would use task scheduler to run the tasks at given times of the day.

Ensure the macro's run when the Workbook opens, using something like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'my code or a function call to the code I want to run
End Sub
```

Then, you simply create multiple tasks in Task scheduler and in the New Action window, sett the arguments and program path, the program path being Excel and the arguments being `/e "c:\YourWorkbook.xls"`

This will only work if you know how long each task will take. It will also mean your Excel files will run the macro on load, regardless of how they were opened (which may or may not be desirable).